# Design patterns deemed subjective

Tags: discussion

Subjective topics are discouraged at SO. If this is true, how do you post design
pattern questions without getting marked down?

Maybe there's a productive way to post this topic. Wiki gives a good definition of design pattern in programming. I mean it as a whiteboard idea of what to do.

**Topic marked down**
AS3 design patterns for counters
"people wait to mark me down when I post this topic"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210520/analog-clock-loop-as3

**Topic gets good response**
Any question about building games 'because programmers like that stuff'
["multiply frog enemy" timer and array AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381842/multiply-frog-enemy-timer-and-array-as3)

Comment: Links to questions please.

Comment: If you have 200 rep on SO, you can associate your account here to get 100 rep, so that you can post multiple links if you'd like.

Comment: I did a search on __"as3" and "design" and "patterns" and "counters"__, and no questions came up.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Recently Closed list about AS3 design patterns. Links or it didn't happen.

Comment: Possibly you don't understand what is meant by a "design pattern" by programmers.

Comment: Looks like he has 3 different accounts on SO?

Comment: @Jon: The original post said "tried and failed" / "tried and succeeded" so it looks like they were real questions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Jon picked the right questions (and it definitely looks like he did), then you're asking about a question that received **one** stray downvote.  Based on the title, I expected that the questions had been closed as `Subjective/Argumentative`, but that's not the case here.

I doubt that the downvote on the first question had anything to do with the question being *subjective* - if that were the case, it would likely have been closed.  It also wasn't downvoted to oblivion, it was only downvoted once; all that means is that one person saw your question and didn't like it.

My best guess as to why is that you seem to be asking a very basic question (how to write a loop), and whoever downvoted was having a bad day and decided that it was a "stupid" question, or perhaps a homework question.  But I don't know that for sure - the fact of the matter is, people aren't obligated to explain their downvotes and *one* downvote (as opposed to a torrent of downvotes) doesn't really mean all that much.

As a rule, people will be nicer to you if you:

- Tag such questions with `beginner` (full disclosure, so people don't assume it's homework etc.);
- Use more precise titles, such as *How do I create a continuous animation for an analog clock?*

They really weren't bad questions, IMO, it's just that they were awkwardly worded and a little RTFM-ish.

By the way, neither of those questions have anything to do with [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: I copy/pasted the links from the link he posted (see the edit history).

Answer (score 1):

First, In most of your questions (including this one) people are asking stuff in comments and you're not answering them, so they have no idea what you want.

Second, I don't see any of your questions that ask about design patterns.  Do you understand what 'design pattern' means in the programming world?

Third, I don't know why you re-edited to say "people wait to make me down", that doesn't mean anything, don't you mean "mark me down".  What do you mean?

Please don't ignore all the questions about your question, answer them.

Comment: First is answered. Second, it may mean something different to me. Three, sorry about the spelling.

Comment: @videodnd, OK, see the link that ladybug killer put in the comments.

Comment: @videodnd, why do you say your clock question got a poor response, when you accepted an answer and said it was fantastic.  One good answer is all you should need (and what SO aims for).

Comment: The question's a scenario, it's not really about me. I did want to clear up some of the problems I'm having in the SO community, before posting more stuff that's too amateur or subjective. I post about building counters in AS3.

Comment: HERE"S ONE: This one got renamed and completely overhauled. It was originally marked down. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538483/best-practices-for-handling-math-calculations-in-a-flash-project

Comment: @videodnd,  I think the editor did a good job with the question, and you got a good answer.  I guess what you need to do most is approach the way you ask your questions like a programming project, design and then careful implementation.  First impressions mean a lot in all aspects of life.

Comment: @videodnd: The original version of that question made no sense. It basically seemed to just be saying "I hate math."  Good for you. The fact that it got completely rewritten and subsequently upvoted is a testament to the determination of many SO users to help out in any way they can.

Comment: @videodnd: please read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq. It seems you're surprised that your questions are being edited.

Comment: @videodnd:  I don't like questions about hypothetical scenarios.  It may have something to do with having "YAGNI" pounded into my brain for years.  (You Ain't Gonna Need It, meaning "don't overdesign".)  If you have complaints about how some questions are handled, please post links so we can see the actual problem.  If you can't find links, then why should we think there's a problem?

Comment: @videodnd:  Also, I don't care what you mean by "design pattern".  It has a meaning that's clear to most people in the field, and using it in a different way is going to help nobody, including you.  Language does drift, but if it's going to be useful for communication it has to drift slowly.